# Where in Mongoose or MongoDB to put Calculations and Formulas?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am designing a huge applications where we have to perform the same calculations on every Mongo document, e.g.:

```
{
    field1:field1,
    field2:field2
    sum:(field1+field2)
}
```

Where to put such kind of calculations best? Into Mongoose Model or Schema, MongoDB itself or even into our controller in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform queries on the data or if the calculation is complicated, it makes sense to add a simple field for the result and store that in the MongoDB document. MongoDB has no knowledge about the fact that some of the fields are related, it's your job to keep the data in sync.

If you don't need queries and if the calculation is not complicated, the best place is usually the model, because it allows both "backend" services and frontend services to query the fields and the (domain) logic is coded into the model in a central location rather than spread across half the code base.

I'd only put such logic in the frontend if it's a read-only and frontend-only matter, for instance, you might want to perform number formatting through an angular *filter* and perform calculations and data storage with full precision.

The angular controller should only be concerned with frontend logic, e.g. managing the order of how a user selects from a variety of options that are mutually exclusive or depends on each other. The frontend controller should not have the slightest idea about domain logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by "domain logic"? I agree with you and I am thinking of saving the financial calculations into Mongo and letting the Model make use of it. In addition the user will be able to change these calculation formulas from the front end. I know, not your everyday app.

Comment: "domain logic" is the kind of logic that you'd need to do even without a computer, say "the gross is the net multiplied by 1 plus the tax over 100". So a function `getGross() { return net * (1 + tax/100.0); }` would be domain logic, and the domain model approach is that it shouldn't sit in the controller, the database or the frontend, but in the model itself. Alternatively, you could use a `TaxCaluclationService` that performs the calculation and outputs a dto that simply has two fields for gross and net, but doesn't know they are related.See http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html

Comment: Thank you @mnemosyn. I agree it should sit in the Model or maybe in the API if not possible in the model. Please also this follow-up thread, which gets more technical: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-users/lzyjg0b8Vn0